# Monitor don't display anything after I connect PC to LCD TV

Tags: windows-7, display, connection, lcd

I have a 19" samsung monitor and a LCD TV. Firstly, I connect my pc to LCD TV with vga cable. Then I unpluged cabble and connect it to my monitor. But now I can't see anything on the monitor. Do anyone know why had it gone?

Comment: Can you list the exact models of both Samsung monitor and LCD TV?  Also, what resolution and refresh rate do they use?

Comment: I have a possibly related issue with an LCD TV over DVI->HDMI, I need to reboot the computer to get the screen to show again. I think it has something to do with the graphics output adjusting itself to a particular monitor, and failing to readjust when you switch to a monitor that needs different parameters. Rebooting works, still looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resolution or frequency of your LCD TV may be set too high (or low) for your regular screen.
Try reconnecting the LCD TV and lowering the resolution or frequency before connecting the Samsung monitor again.

If that doesn't help, rebooting to safe mode and selecting the *Plug and play monitor* driver for your screen may help.

Comment: I think you are right but how can ı do with no display?

Comment: Reconnecting the LCD TV would allow you to change the settings. If that's not possible, a reboot probably solves the issue.